# Patach with chet

Tags: grammar-dikduk, vowels-nekudot

Is there any instance in which a final chet takes a regular patach, rather than a patach ganuv? This also goes for 'ayin and hey mapik.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hebrew words never end in a short vowel (including *patach*). There are plenty of words ending with a *patach* and then a *chet*, such as פֶּסַח, פֵּתַח, שָׁמַע, and גָּבַהּ.

Comment: What about Peh = mouth

Comment: @DoubleAA That has a letter (*hei*) after the *segol*.

Comment: ??? That's a mater lectionis not a consonant.

Comment: @DoubleAA Still, the word doesn't end with the *segol*, rather with a letter.

Comment: I guess it depends how you define letter. It's written with a glyph, but the glyph is completely functionless.